# Root relative vs document relative paths in web development

Tags: apache, comparison, relative-path

I feel like root relative paths would be better, but I can't think of any actual reasons why. Is one way more secure? Does one offer more flexibility? I'm looking for stuff like that.

For example, consider that `http://domainname.com/path/to/css/styles.css` contains:

```
.root-relative {
  background-image: url('/path/to/css/images/someimage.png');
}
.doc-relative {
  background-image: url('images/someimage.png');
}
```

It goes beyond just CSS though, like specifying URLs for AJAX calls in JavaScript functions:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'ajax/somefile.php',
  type: 'post',
  // etc...

// Or this way?
$.ajax({
  url: '/longer/full/path/ajax/somefile.php',
  type: 'post',
  // etc...
```

Then of course there is a lot of magic that can be done with .htaccess. I use .htaccess for URL rewriting, but have left that out of the example because it makes it unnecessarily complicated, so don't get too caught up with the examples here.

I'm just generally wondering if there are any actual benefits or disadvantages for either way.